# Passport stamped across B1 visa upon entry in the USA

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I have been to the USA under a B1/B2 visa previously, but then it was stamped on the page opposite to the one with the visa, where b2 was written and the deadline for exit was stamped.

The next time when I entered with a B1/B2, the stamp was put halfway across the page opposite the visa and halfway right over the visa, where B1 was written and the deadline for exit was stamped.

Does this mean anything? The visa is marked M, which I suppose means multiple-entry, and it still has a few years of validity remaining. Is this still the case now that it has been stamped across? Is there any way I can verify the validity of my visa?

Answer (score 15):

The location of the entry stamp has absolutely no meaning.

US immigration staff will normally put the stamp on the page opposite the visa, but it is not uncommon for them to put it partially on the visa page, or even on a completely different page.

My current US visa has 3 entry stamps that partially cover the visa page, 3 that are entirely on the opposite page, and several that are on different pages and none of these have ever caused me any issues when re-entering the country.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm visa validity online or something?

Comment: @user13267 the visa validity is until the expiration date printed on the visa.  There is no way to check that online (nor is there any need to do so, of course).  The date by which you must leave the US is entirely unrelated to the visa validity, and you may be able to look that up at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov, although if you have a paper I-94 it may not be reflected in the database.  If you have more than one I-94, the most recent applies.

Comment: The odds of your visa being canceled without your (at least partial) knowledge is basically zero. If you suspect you've broken the conditions of your visa (overstayed, committed a crime, etc) then you could contact the local US consulate to confirm - but doing this based on the stamps on your visa is unnecessary and pointless.

Comment: *The location of the entry stamp has absolutely no meaning* - I'm not sure this is entirely correct.  When we got our B1/B2 visas in May, on our first entry into the US after that the CBP officer was training another officer, and explained that on *first* entry they are to stamp across the visa (part on the blank page, part on the visa) and write a note (I don't recall what the note is about)

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't a standard for where they stamp - just that the positioning doesn't change anything as far as visa validity. It is potentially a security mechanism to determine if the passport/visa has been modified - but again not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: @Midavalo I've only been to the US once, in September, and my passport was stamped on the opposite page, no written notes. The guy who handled me seemed pretty senior (late 40s - early 50s), so that might be a new tradition.

Comment: The stamp should have the words 'Class' and 'Until' on it, where they should write the status you have been admitted under (eg, B1, B2, WT for visa waiver tourist, etc) and the date you may remain inside the US until. They are always supposed to include these details, but in my experience maybe 10% of the time they do not.  If they did not, you can given the details on the CBP website - www.cbp.gov/i94

Answer (score 1):

The entry stamp can be stamped anywhere in the passport, not just on or close to the visa. It has no effect on your status in the US

The visa validity shows how long you can use the visa for entry (since it's a multiple-entry visa, you can visit as many times as you want during that period)

The date on the entry stamp shows when you have to finish that specific visit.

Comment: Downvoting because saying that "the US stamps either the opposite page close to the visa, or on half of each page so that the stamp partially touches the visa" is totally false. Immigration officers can and will stamp anywhere in your passport that they like, however most likely on the first available page.

Comment: My US visa is on page 15 of my passport. My latest entry stamp is on page 17. The one before that, page 25.  This despite there still being room on the page opposite my visa.

Comment: @zundi Edited....